# issue with search form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, http-post

im developping a plugin that have a custom search page for a custom post, i have create my custom page like this

```
<?php


/*
Template Name: search-sa_notification
*/?>

<?php get_header(); ?>             
<section class="mo-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-9 columns">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <br /><br /><br />
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="something" name="cernmb" /><br />
                <input class="button small yellow" type="submit" value="search" name="submit" />
                <input class="button small yellow" type="hidden" value="test" name="sbtn" />
            </form>
        </div>
   </div>   
</div>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['sbtn']=='test'){
        echo "ur number is ".$_POST['cernmb']."\n";
    }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

the problem im facing is that when i click on search i got redircted to index page while me i wanna stay in this search page and display the msg in test condition but i got redircted to index page instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this line is your problem:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

When I put that in different template files on a WordPress site, it always echo's out the path to the index.php. Try making that the path to the template file instead.

If you want the form to be submitted back to the same page, just leave the action attr blank:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: nope that doesn't work, it print the path but i got an error that fire fox can't open that kind of files wich is normal since its a php file

Comment: Have you tried leaving action blank? I'll adjust my answer

Comment: i have remove action and it works perfectly now, thank you dear